# How do you use `@Selector` in `@WriteOperation` in Spring Boot 2.0 actuator endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am implementing a custom endpoint with the following class:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "bootstrap")
public class BootstrapUrlEndpoint {

  private final URL bootstrapUrl;

  @Autowired
  public BootstrapUrlEndpoint(URL bootstrapUrl) {
    this.bootstrapUrl = bootstrapUrl;
  }

  @ReadOperation
  public Map<String, String> getBootstrapUrl() {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("bootstrap_url", bootstrapUrl.toExternalForm());
    return result;
  }

  @WriteOperation
  public void setBootstrapUrl(@Selector String property, String value) throws MalformedURLException {
    System.out.println(String.format(">>> Setting  %s = %s", property, value));
  }
}
```

This all "works as intended" **without** the `@Selector` annotation; omitting it and sending a `POST` to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/bootstrap` with:

```
{
  "value": "http://localhost:27017/tables/application"
}
```

invokes the method as expected.

However, I cannot make the "selector" work; I see in the startup logs that it is registered as a valid endpoint:

```
Mapped "{[/actuator/bootstrap/{arg0}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public org.reactivestreams....ava.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
```

Unfortunately, invoking it with `POST /actuator/bootstrap/myprop` and the same body, yields a `400 Bad Request` without either an error log or an error message.

I have been looking for more info and possibly an example: the only relevant (but, alas, incomplete) example I could find was [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-20) - would anyone know what's missing in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just running into the same problem as you and getting a little bit crazy, by the way.

But I found that the problem is related to parameter naming of the parameters annotated with `@Selector`.

All will work if you name your var "property" as "arg0" like this:

```
public void setBootstrapUrl(@Selector String arg0, String value)
```

Yes, I know this is a little weird but I found some info in this [article](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11010) talking about embedding parameter when compiling the classes.

I still don't really got this working using my own names in the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround suggested by Angel Pizano solves the problem indeed, but here's a better solution: enable parameters flag for maven compiler plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here's a related thread by the way: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11010

Answer (score 3):

Indeed both solutions here will work but since version 3.6.2, maven-compiler-plugin supports a new configuration element 'parameters' which you must set to 'true'.

This generates some extra metadata for methods reflection which can be used by spring at startup to correctly bind your parameters. See [maven-compiler-plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#parameters).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```